# FullCalendar Button Placement Month Name should be between left and right arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar javascript plugin and it's the best!

I was hoping if there's a way I can change the button placement. It should look like this [image]

As you can see the Month Name is in between the Left and Right arrow. I've been reading the [buttonText](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs1/text/buttonText/) documentation but can't imagine how to achieve that kind of button placement.

Is that even possible? Hopefully it is! Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That also sounds a good idea @drip, I was looking for a cleaner approach, like its already built in in the plugin. If there's no trick left, then i'll do what you suggested. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for fullcalendar, you need to look at the header page

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/header/

I believe you should have

```
{
  right:  'prev, title, next'
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's how is it is?! You saved my life! :)